# If 2 different strings from 2 different MYSQLi columns match then count for each ID of a different column using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a table using PHP to show the name of a predictor and how many successful predictions and how many unsuccessful predictions they have made.

The outcome should look like this.

| Predictor Name | Predictor Record (Wins/Losses) |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | 0/0 |
| name2 | 0/0 |

PHP
In truth I am a little lost on how to set things up.

```
<table class="table-styling">
          <tr>
            <th>Predictor Name</th>
            <th>Full Record (Wins/Losses)</th>
          </tr> 

        <?php
        $sql = 'SELECT predictors.predictor_id, predictors.predictor_name, predictions.base_prediction, matches.base_result, predictions.specific_prediction, 
                       matches.specific_result, predictions.super_specific_prediction, matches.super_specific_result    
                FROM predictions 
                INNER JOIN matches ON matches.match_id = predictions.match_id
                INNER JOIN predictors ON predictors.predictor_id = predictions.predictor_id';

        $results = $mysqli->query($sql);

        

        if($results->num_rows) {
          while ($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>$row->predictor_name</td> 
                    <td>$basePredictionWins/$basePredictionLosses</td>
                  </tr>";
          }

          if ($row->base_result === $row->base_prediction) {
            $basePredictionWins = array_count_values($results);
          }
          if ($row->base_result !== $row->base_prediction) {
            $basePredictionLosses = array_count_values($results);
          }

        }


        ?>

        </table>
```

The main issue seems to be these IF statements

```
if ($row->base_result === $row->base_prediction) {
            $basePredictionWins = array_count_values($results);
          }
if ($row->base_result !== $row->base_prediction) {
            $basePredictionLosses = array_count_values($results);
          }
```

MYSQLi create tables

```
Matches

CREATE TABLE `matches` (

 `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

 `match_date` date NOT NULL,

 `match_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

 `base_result` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

 `specific_result` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

 `super_specific_result` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

 `sport_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

 `organisation_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY (`match_id`),

 KEY `match_date` (`match_date`),

 KEY `match_name` (`match_name`),

 KEY `sport_id` (`sport_id`),

 KEY `organisation_id` (`organisation_id`),

 KEY `base_result` (`base_result`) USING BTREE,

 KEY `specific_result` (`specific_result`) USING BTREE,

 KEY `super_specific_result` (`super_specific_result`) USING BTREE,

 CONSTRAINT `matches_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`organisation_id`) REFERENCES `organisation` (`organisation_id`),

 CONSTRAINT `matches_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sport_id`) REFERENCES `sports` (`sport_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Predictors

CREATE TABLE `predictors` (

 `predictor_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

 `predictor_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY (`predictor_id`),

 KEY `predictor_name` (`predictor_name`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Predictions

CREATE TABLE `predictions` (

 `prediction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

 `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

 `predictor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

 `base_prediction` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

 `specific_prediction` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

 `super_specific_prediction` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY (`prediction_id`),

 KEY `match_id` (`match_id`),

 KEY `predictor_id` (`predictor_id`),

 CONSTRAINT `predictions_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`predictor_id`) REFERENCES `predictors` (`predictor_id`),

 CONSTRAINT `predictions_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`match_id`) REFERENCES `matches` (`match_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: can you create a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) and include a minimal sample data and the expected result that corresponds to this. Are you intentionally using assignment `=` and `/=` operators within an `if` statement? If this is a 1-> many join (at least on matches), is there a `group by` missing?

Comment: Hi, you are correct, I used the wrong syntax for matches by using = instead of === and /= instead of !==, I have now edited this in the question. How would you set up a group by statement in this. I am a little lost on that dbfiddle website and don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

With your SQL you want to `GROUP BY` the `predictor_id` so there is only 1 predictor per line. After that you can use the SQL `SUM` to add up the results of the matches.  The `=` in SQL is a comparison resulting in 0 for false and 1 for true. So just adding those up gets the total wins/losses.

```
SELECT predictors.predictor_id,
       predictors.predictor_name,
       SUM(matches.base_result = predictions.base_prediction) as WINS
       SUM(matches.base_result != predictions.base_prediction) as LOSSES  
FROM predictions 
INNER JOIN matches ON matches.match_id = predictions.match_id
INNER JOIN predictors ON predictors.predictor_id = predictions.predictor_id
GROUP BY predictions.predictor_id
```